# GSON,AndroidAnnotations - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String

Tags: gson, android-annotations

I searched similar topics but none of them helped me.

My JSON response is:

```
{
"success": "true",
"data": {
    "id": "x",
    "user_name": "xxx",
    "email": "xxx@xxx.com",
    "first_name": "xxx",
    "last_name": "xx",
    "position": "xxx",
    "session_id": "xxx"
}
```

}

My Java classes are:

Response:

```
public class Response {

public String success;
public Data data;

public Response() {
}
public Response(String success, Data data) {

    this.success = success;
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

Data

```
public class Data {

public String id;
public String user_name;
public String email;
public String first_name;
public String last_name;
public String position;
public String session_id;

public Data() {
}

public Data(String id, String user_name, String email, String first_name, String last_name, String position, String session_id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.user_name = user_name;
    this.email = email;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.position = position;
    this.session_id = session_id;
}
```

}

I am using android annotations to establish rest connection.
My RestClient is:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://xxx/services", converters = {GsonHttpMessageConverter.class})

public interface MyRestClient {

    @Post("/login.php")
    ResponseEntity<Response> login(User user);

    RestTemplate getRestTemplate();

    void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate);
}
```

And in main activity I use:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> resp = restCli.login(new User("xxx","xxx"));
```

I get an error

```
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was String at line 1 column 4
```

I tried to change 'success' filed type to boolean,Boolean i Java class - didn't help.
I tried changing the method return type in the rest interface to void and then no error, so I think the error is connected with wrong response class, but I have no idea what is wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: Since your class is matching the JSON you provided, would help you if you could post what really the server sends to you. To debug you could try to pass Object instead of Response. Gson will put a map or an array.

Comment: The server sends me exactly the same, I checked it using Postman on Chrome.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to see the server response in plain text from Java Code? (maybe use a different converter or something?)